# How to create and name a new folder from tkinter Entry widget input?

Tags: python, tkinter, os.path

I want the input, someone has put into the Entry widget (E1) of my Tkinter GUI, to be the name of the new folder, because every time someone inputs something, I need to have a new folder named after the input:

```
def create():
    folder = E1.get()
    newpath = r"C:\Users\....\folder" 
    if not os.path.exists(newpath):
        os.makedirs(newpath)
```

This creates a new folder, but it is named `folder` and not how I want it named (after the numbers entered into the `Entry` box (`E1`)).

Making it:

```
newpath = r"C:\Users\...\E1.get()"
```

gives me a folder called "E1.get()"

And secondly, but that hopefully comes with the answer to the first question, how do I get to see the input, without putting `E1.get()` into a variable? 
So is there a way to see it directly and maybe use that as the name of my new folder?

Comment: Use `newpath = os.path.join(r"C:\Users\Heinrich\Documents\Python\hope\", E1.get()) `

Comment: Running it now, gives me a NameError in the "if-not" statement : name 'os' is not defined. I imported join from os.path so from os.path import join

Comment: import os ......

Comment: _'how do I get to see the input, without putting `E1.get()` into a variable?'_ What do you mean? Can't you visually see what's in the entry? or do you mean like `print(E1.get())`? `E1` is an entry widget and `E1.get()` is simply the `str` representation of what's written in that entry.

Comment: I got it now, thanks a lot everyone !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do this:

- String formatting old style:

  ```
  newpath = r"C:\Users\Heinrich\Documents\Python\hope\%s" % E1.get()
  ```
- String formatting new style:

  ```
  newpath = r"C:\Users\Heinrich\Documents\Python\hope\{}".format(E1.get())
  ```
- Raw f(ormat)-strings (Python 3.6 only):

  ```
  newpath = fr"C:\Users\Heinrich\Documents\Python\hope\{E1.get()}"
  ```
- Use `os.path.join` as @eyllanesc stated:

  ```
  from os.path import join
  newpath = join(r"C:\Users\Heinrich\Documents\Python\hope", '1234'))
  ```